# Concise way to immutably add object to an array that is a property of an object and return the new object

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

Is there a more concise way to functionally add an item to an array that is a property of an object?

Imperative:

```
secitems.sections.push("Test")
return secitems
```

Functional:

```
const R = require("ramada")
return Object.assign({}, secitems, {
                sections: R.append(
                    "Test",
                    secitems.sections
                )
            })
```

My functional version seems too long and complicated compared to the imperative version. Is there a more concise way to write it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update (TL;DR)**

I would do it like this:

```
const seclens = lensProp('sections');
over(seclens, append('Test'), secitems);
//=> {id: 123, sections: ['Foo', 'Bar, 'Test']}
```

---

There are a number of ways to do this more concisely.  Some of them also solve for problems that your original code doesn't handle:

```
// This works fine
const secitems = {id: 123, sections: ['Foo', 'Bar']};
secitems.sections.push("Test")
secitems; //=> {id: 123, sections: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Test']}

// But this is a problem
const secitems = {id: 123};
secitems.sections.push("Test")
secitems; //=> throws "secitems.sections is undefined"
```

My preferred method using Ramda would be to use lenses:

```
const secitems = {id: 123, sections: ['Foo', 'Bar']};

over(lensProp('sections'), append('Test'), secitems);
//=> {id: 123, sections: ['Foo', 'Bar, 'Test']}
```

The advantage of this is that the lens itself is useful in several contexts:

```
const seclens = lensProp('sections');

const getSections = view(seclens);
getSections(secitems); //=> ['Foo', 'Bar']

const setSections = set(seclens);
setSections(['Baz, Qux'], secitems)
//=> {id: 123, sections: ['Baz', 'Qux']}
setSections(['Baz', 'Qux'], {id: 456})
//=> {id: 456, sections: ['Baz', 'Qux']}
```

And if your data structure were to change, the only code that would need to change would be the lens definition itself:

```
const obj = {id: 123, secitems: {sections: ['Foo', 'Bar']}};

over(lensPath(['secitems', 'sections']), append('Test'), obj);
//=> {id: 123, secitems: {sections: ['Foo', 'Bar, 'Test']}}
```

Or

```
const seclens = lensPath(['secitems', 'sections']);

const getSections = view(seclens);
getSections(obj); //=> ['Foo', 'Bar']

const setSections = set(seclens);
setSections(['Baz, Qux'], obj)
//=> {id: 123, secitems: {sections: ['Baz', 'Qux']}}
setSections(['Baz', 'Qux'], {id: 456})
//=> {id: 456, secitems: {sections: ['Baz', 'Qux']}}
```

There is more information in [Ramda's `lens` documentation](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens).

Answer (score 2):

```
const R = require('ramda')
return R.mergeWith(R.concat, secitems, { sections: ["Test"] })
```